Python absolute Imports are not resolved as intended
I work with a large repository (https://github.com/jenellefeather/model_metamers_pytorch). This repository has many packages. All imports are absolute. To run the code the repository says to copy a certain file into a subsubsubdirectory and run it there. But when I enter this subsubsubdirectory and run the code the imports fail.
The needed directories are all installed aswell as all files within so my guess is that the root directory when running isn't working as intended. Is there a way to display the full path of where python looks for the import and to change the root directory so python nows from what level down its supposed to look?
repository/
  dirA/
    __init__.py
    file_to_run.py
    help_function.py
  dirB/
    subdirA/
      __init__.py
      subsubdirA/
        __init__.py
        dataA
      subsubdirB/
        __init__.py
        dataB

I copy file_to_run.py into subdirA and run it with python file_to_run.py
However the import of help_function fails. The import looks like:
form dirA.help_function import function

The needed directories are all installed aswell as all files within so my guess is that the root directory when running isn't working as intended. Is there a way to display the full path of where python looks for the import? And if I run something within subsubdirA is the root directory still repository or is it subsubdirA? and can I change that?

"To run the code I need to run the repository says to copy a certain file into a subsubsubdirectory and run it there." that does not bode well.

" Is there a way to display the full path of where python looks for the import?" yes, sys.path

"And if I run something within subsubdirA is the root directory still repository or is it subsubdirA? " What do you mean by "root directory"?

"The needed directories are all installed as well as all files within" what does that mean exactly? I would typically assumed that meant "this repo has been pip installed", but according to the docs, that isn't possible since it isn't actually packaged

Unfortunately, you are going to find that there is a lot of poorly packaged software out there in the academic world. Python packaging can take a bit of work and is a bit wonky, but frankly, when they are asking you to put a file in a specific part of the directory tree and run it from there.... that is basically a horrible mess.

1.) Sorry forthe messed up sentence.I edited it.   2.) By root directory is the 'highest' directory where python starts to look.     3.) I cloned the repository and ran download_large_files.py    4.) It might be messy but since this code belongs to a paper published in nature it seems to work and I'm trying to get it working but so far it hasn't.                                   Your comment about syspath was helpfull as the directory im working in isn't part of syspath. Only multiple paths from my conda enviorment. Can I just do sys.path.append and then my directory?

The import system looks through sys.path, the first entry is the directory that includes the input script, but that doesn't really matter. Unfortuantly, since the directions are telling you to place the script in a particular place, it seems they are relying on this behavior (they really really shouldn't). Anyway, I hate to be the bearer of bad news, but just because a paper was published in Nature doesn't mean that the repository is set up to be reproducibly run.

You can .append to sys.path, although, that is a hack that really isn't a good solution,but something like that might work. The other option is to use PYTHONPATH=<whatever> python my_script.py and whatever is in PYTHONPATH will be prepended to sys.path. The problem is they have basically admitted that this project isn't properly packaged when they state "Currently, the repository is not set up for pip installation." That basically is synonymous with "this isn't packaged at all". They probably got it to work in their environment and don't really understand why it works

Since I have to get it to work I will try with .append and see if that helps. Thanks
